# Un-able to un-compress the xml returned from the service in the windows phone 7 application?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone 7 app , in which my application is consuming the response of my services.

my service is giving a response of xml(string) , since the xml size is very large i had compressed the xml using :-

```
    public static string Compress(string text)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        ms.Position = 0;
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

        byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

        byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(gzBuffer);
    }
```

i have compressed the data using the GZipStream class and adding the namespace using System.IO.Compression but

my problem is that :-

i am not able to un-compress it in that client side(windows phone 7 app) , i tried to add that dll in the windows phone 7 app project

it says:- system.Io.Compression dll cannnot be added because it was not built using windows phone 7 runtime, windows phone projects will work with windows phone assemblies only.

Am i doing any thing wrong , is there any better way of doing.

can you let me know the optimal solution?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone cannot reference desktop .NET libraries, but there is no equivalent for Windows Phone.

There is a third party library that simplifies zip requests:

- Add a package (NuGet) reference to [Delay.GzipWebClient](http://nuget.org/packages/Delay.GzipWebClient)
- Add the following code to your startup:

_

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", SharpGIS.WebRequestCreator.GZip);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", SharpGIS.WebRequestCreator.GZip);
```

From that point on, any web requests will automatically request zipped responses and they will be uncompressed by the time your application code gets them.